# Views table output change row into column

Tags: 7, views

In Drupal 7, I have Views table-output like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| Tool   | Status   | Number |
+--------+----------+--------+
| Hammer | Broken   | 3      |
| Hammer | Borrowed | 10     |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

I want to change the output into:

```
+--------+--------+----------+
| Tool   | Broken | Borrowed |
+--------+--------+----------+
| Hammer | 3      | 10       |
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Is this possible? I prefer without custom coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use views template, In `advanced` section, there is an option for theming - `Theme:Information`. Choose template from there or simply use `views-view-table--yourviewname.tpl.php`.

debug your rows here and add css classes to customize the output as per you want.

Take below code as a reference.

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Template to display a view as a table.
 *
 * - $title : The title of this group of rows.  May be empty.
 * - $header: An array of header labels keyed by field id.
 * - $caption: The caption for this table. May be empty.
 * - $header_classes: An array of header classes keyed by field id.
 * - $fields: An array of CSS IDs to use for each field id.
 * - $classes: A class or classes to apply to the table, based on settings.
 * - $row_classes: An array of classes to apply to each row, indexed by row
 *   number. This matches the index in $rows.
 * - $rows: An array of row items. Each row is an array of content.
 *   $rows are keyed by row number, fields within rows are keyed by field ID.
 * - $field_classes: An array of classes to apply to each field, indexed by
 *   field id, then row number. This matches the index in $rows.
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
$i = 0;
$cnt = count($rows);
?>

<?php foreach ($rows as $row_count => $row): ?> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="bod-item">
        <div class="member-wrapper" id="<?php print $row_count; ?>">
            <?php
            $url = $row['field_profile_image'];
            ?>

        </div>  
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve this, using these modules: views_php and views_aggregator.

With option **use aggregation ON** and using views_php, I create two **Global PHP Fields** which utilize `$data` variable.

Then, using views_aggregator table format, I apply **Group Function** to the Global PHP Fields above.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is no **easy** solution to create such kind of view using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module. The previous answers seem to somehow confirm this.

However the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer) can be used for this type of reporting. More specifically by using its facility to create a [Display of a table in ***crosstab*** format](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.renderers#frxcrosstab).

A ***crosstab*** table is a table with a special layout. It is formatted as a grid, with:

- the **rows** representing one or more (combinations of) facts, such as countries or regions, names of persons (or users) like employees / salespeople (or user IDs / user names), etc.
- the **columns** representing one or more other facts, such as periods (months of a year, years, etc), available types/flavors of something (like types of errors), etc.
- the **intersections of rows and columns** containing the actual information (data), such as summarized information (counts of something), timestamps, etc. and which might (optionally) **include a hyperlink to a drill-down report**.

Below is a sample of a ***crosstab*** report (including drilldown links also, i.e. the numbers in red in it):

[image]

Refer to [my comment in the Forena issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2337327#comment-9143781) for more details about the above screenshot. And/or have a look at the video about [How to generate crosstab reports with graphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZY5T3kPXZc) (Forena also supports charting of those data, a typical related requirement ...).